# Insert Image Script does not work when called within Html Link

Tags: javascript, php, html

My index.html Code contains `href="projects/my-project-ins.html"`

```
       <div class="vcenter">
          <a href="projects/my-project-ins.html" title="My Project" class="open-btn"></a>
          <p class="portfolio-tags">
              <a href="#a" title="Design">Design</a>
          </p>
       </div><!-- End .portfolio-overlay -->
```

`my-project-ins.html` contains just the following code and nothing else

```
<div class="row single-portfolio" id="project-content">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="carousel-container valign">
            <div class="owl-carousel single-portfolio-slider">
                 <script src="../php/ins-imgs.php"></script>
            </div><!-- End .single-portfolio-slider -->
        </div><!-- End .carousel-container -->
    </div><!-- End .col-md-7 -->
</div>
```

When calling this html file in the `url www.example.com/projects/my-project-ins.html` the script is called and the images are displayed, however when I call it through the index.html file i do not see the images called by the script. 
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Both `index.html` & `my-project-ins.html` files are in same folder in this case `projects`?

Comment: no my-project-ins.html is in the projects folder and the index is in the root folder

Comment: then set relative paths..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to run this from a server, with PHP enabled. If you're loading it locally from the filesystem, the PHP file you're requesting is unable to do its magic.

Comment: Is there no way of implicitly calling it ?

Comment: The work you'd have to do to fake it is far less that the work you would have to do to simply set up a php-enabled server on your computer.